# JavaScript not executing in html file that is rendered using knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am rendering a html template using ko.renderTemplate method and I can see the html being rendered. There is a script tag  in the same file which is not executing though.

```
<div>
<div>
    <script>
       $(function () {
           alert("yes");
       });
    </script>
</div>
</div>
```

I don't see the alert message.

Comment: Is the `<script>` part of the template?

Comment: Yes, it is included in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the document ready would be triggered with the rendering of a template.

Surely you should be using afterrender in you binding to run another script function.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove